# Not declared context error using context hook in react with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

just asking for some help with this basic implementation with hooks. I am currently working with Next.js and want to set a context in the _app.js file in order to make it available to the entire component tree.

```
import React from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const dataContext = React.createContext()
  return (
    <dataContext.Provider value = 'just some text'>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </dataContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

Then in the index.js, add the component loginForm.js with the following code:

```
import React from "react";

function LoginForm (props) {

  const info = React.useContext(dataContext)
  const onSubmit = () => console.log(info)

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <button type="submit">click here</button>
   </form>
)
}
```

now in the console, I receive an error that says "dataContext is not declared"

[image: Apparently the context exists]

- Apparently, the context exists -

This is so simple that I don't even know how to tackle the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to access the same instance of `dataContext` that's been declared in the `_app`. Try exporting it where you're declaring it `export const DataContext = React.createContext();` then import and use it in the `LoginForm` component: `import { DataContext } from '<path-to/pages/_app'` & `const info = React.useContext(DataContext)`. Have a read through the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is dataContext in index.js?

```
 const info = React.useContext(dataContext)
```

I think you forgot to import the context

Answer (score 0):

Move `React.createContext()` outside the component:

```
import React from "react";

const DataContext = React.createContext();

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value="just some text">
      <Component { ...pageProps } />
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, unfortunately, the error persists.

Comment: @CristianDiaz Are you on the latest Next.js version? It might be related to this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18090

Comment: Yes, I am working with Next v12.0.1, not sure if it is related to that issue, since in the description they receive an "undefined" value, in my case, it is basically that the context hook is not connecting to the context provider as if I were using a wrong name or if the context was set in another branch in the component tree, it does not appear to be the case. The most upsetting side is that this is not even something complex, it makes me feel so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = useMyContextHook()
const draw = d ? d.draw : null
```

This fixed it for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.